# Core Data keeps two objects instead 27 in fetchObjects

Tags: ios, json, core-data

First step:
Upload from Json data(total of data = 27 objects) then i want keep all this objects in my Core Data;
Second Step:
After time period i checking my Json again for new objects. Compare Core Data objects count with Json objects count, if its different i going to add this objects to my Core Data. But my Core Data has a wrong objects count on the second step(2 objects in fetchObjects).
In summary i would like to copy all objects from Json to my Core Data and each ten seconds i check for new objects in my Json.
Here is my following code:

```
- (NSInteger) isNewData: (NSArray *) fetchedObjects
{
    ///////////json part
    NSURLRequest* urlRequest =  [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL          URLWithString:getMessageURL] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
    NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    _json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    ///////////core data part
    //NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    /*NSError *error;
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];*/
    /////////if part
    NSLog(@"%d",fetchedObjects.count);
    return _json.count - fetchedObjects.count;
}

- (void) loadDataToCoreDataFromJson: (NSInteger) odds andSecond: (NSManagedObjectContext *) context
{
    //core data connection
    Entity *newList = [NSEntityDescription
                   insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entity"
                   inManagedObjectContext:context];
    newList = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    for (int i = 0; i < odds; i++)//?
    {
        //NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

        newList.login = [[_json objectAtIndex:_json.count - odds + i] objectForKey:@"login"];
        newList.message = [[_json objectAtIndex:_json.count - odds + i] objectForKey:@"message"];
        newList.date = [[_json objectAtIndex:_json.count - odds + i] objectForKey:@"date"];
        [context save:nil];
    }

}

- (void) loadDataFromCoreDataToArrays : (NSArray*) fetchedObjects
{
    _getDate = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _getMessage = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _getLogin = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    ///////////core data part connection
    //NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    for (int i = 0; i < fetchedObjects.count; i++)
    {
        Entity * info = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:i];
        [_getLogin addObject:info.login];
        [_getMessage addObject:info.message];
        [_getDate addObject:info.date];
    }

}

- (void) chating
{
    AppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
    NSError *error;
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    NSInteger odds = [self isNewData: fetchedObjects]; //0 if no data, if > 0 then there are N new data;
    if (odds != 0)
    {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
        [self loadDataToCoreDataFromJson: odds andSecond:context];
        [self loadDataFromCoreDataToArrays: fetchedObjects];
        [self reloadMyTableView];
    }
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    _buttonSend.enabled = NO;
    [self loadUserDefault];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        _connects++;
        NSLog(@"return message");
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(chating) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
            [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(reloadMyTableView) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        });
    });
}
```

I think i doing wrong with Core Data. Thanks every body for help.

Answer (score 0):

As a guideline:

1. Don't load synchronously, choose asynchronous instead
2. Don't rely on counts, it might work now but comparing unique identifiers is a much better long term solution
3. Send the server information about what you already have so it doesn't need to tell you about those things again (save bandwidth, make users happy)
4. Always verify the result and then, if appropriate, check the `error` returned from an API that offers it - like when saving the context or executing a fetch request
5. Don't start timers without keeping a reference to them - you really need to be able to `invalidate` them later on...

Also, when you call `loadDataFromCoreDataToArrays:` you don't have all of the objects in `fetchedObjects` - you have added them to the context, but you haven't added them to `fetchedObjects` or re-fetched.

Comment: how can i get all objects from Core Data in loadDataFromCoreDataToArrays and how i should add in fetchObjects. Thank you for answer.

Comment: Don't just check the error.  Check the response from the method.  If that response indicates an error **THEN** check the error.

Comment: @user3813671 add items to the array (make it mutable), which is more efficient than running a new fetch request.